# Uploading Data For A New Column In MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've added a new column to a database and want to populate it from a spreadsheet.  Is there an  easy query that will grab the data out based on another column in the spreadsheet that matches the one in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two ways:

Edit the spreadsheet, create a formula like

```
="update mytable set mynewcolumn = " + A1 + " where " + B1 + " = primaryKeyColumn"
```

where A1 represents the first cell with data and B1 is the primary key value to the row that will be updated.  Then drag the cell down by the lower right corner so the formula is repeated.  Copy the text produced by the formula, paste into SQL Mgmt Studio and run.

Or, you can use MSSQL's import engine which allows you to select a spreadsheet as your datasource.  From there you can map your column to the new column.

Comment: or you could save the spreadsheet to a CSV file and use an appropriate global editing command with regular expressions to change each line.

Comment: Sorry... answer should have been UPDATE not INSERT.  Answer updated.

Comment: When I use the import engine how do I make sure it adds it to the right row in the table?

Comment: the "where" clause will ensure you add it to the correct row, by saying something like "where id=#"

Comment: @Intelwalk - do you have a second column in your spreadsheet that has the primary key or something else related to the data?

Comment: @ChrisGessler Yes I do have another column related to the data

Comment: @Intelwalk - then you're all set.  When you do the import, you can specify a where clause.

Comment: This is GREAT! I understand the ="update..." line now! this is going to make alot of updates EASY!  YOU DA MAN!

Comment: @ChrisGessler Do you know the easiest way to do this with dates? I don't get a good value from the expression I built

Comment: @Intelwalk - yes, format the date to be 'YYYYMMDD' and SQL should read it in as a DATE or DATETIME.